# Symfony DQL Error on join + group by : Expected litteral, got 'BY'

Tags: symfony, group-by, dql

I have two entities, `Product` and `Keyword` with a ManyToMany relation.
I want to get all keywords and for each keyword the number of occurences it is linked to a product.

I'm using DQL. I first tried to use the jointable in my query but I found that it wasn't a good way of doing it. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534991/dql-query-with-joining-table-and-two-join), which is quite similar to what I want to achieve, but I get an error.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT k.id, k.value, count(p.id)
FROM App\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword k
JOIN App\AppBundle\Entity\Product p
GROUP BY p.id
```

Here is the error I get :

`Error : Expected Literal, got 'BY'`.

I am unable to see what's wrong.
Any advice is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you join, you do so using the property name, so it is probably something like

```
SELECT k.id, k.value, count(p.id)
FROM App\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword k
JOIN k.products p
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: if my answer is correct, my rep points would appreciate it if you would accept it as the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
SELECT k.id, k.value, count(p.id)
FROM App\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword k
JOIN App\AppBundle\Entity\Product p
GROUP BY k.id
```

Comment: Yes, but this is semantically different from what I want. I tried anyway to see if the error would disappear but it's still there.