# ManytoMany Entities Select Query Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, entities

I am trying to run a query. I have two many to many entities.

My query for these both entities below

```
  $query = $user->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->join('u.products', ua')
              ->Where('ua.id In (:uproducts)')
              ->setParameters(array(
                  'uproducts' => $userproducts ))
              ->getQuery();

              $query = $user->createQueryBuilder('u')
                  ->join('u.price,'up')
                  ->Where('up.id In (:uprice)')
                  ->setParameters(array(
                      'uprice'=>$userprice))
                  ->getQuery();
```

If i do that in two queries like that it works. But I want that in 1 select query. Is there any idea how I could do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = $user->createQueryBuilder('u')
          ->join('u.products', 'ua')
          ->join('u.price,'up')
          ->Where('ua.id In :uproducts')
          ->andWhere('up.id In :uprice')
          ->setParameters(
             array (
                'uproducts' => $userproducts,
                'uprice'=>$userprice 
              ) 
            )
          ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thank You but I tried this before and I am getting a different Result.

Comment: It's normal that you have two different results, because you are making two joints on the same query.

Comment: Yes but I want all the result what I am getting in these two queries. Can I use union or something like that.

Comment: Look at this please http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: I cant use all the Joins in Doctrine. Can u have an example for me

Comment: No, you can uste all the joins  look at this ; 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534991/dql-query-with-joining-table-and-two-join. Otherwise, try the old school way ! http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html.